# In SAPUI5, how use sap.m.Image with UseMap and get the clicked location?

Tags: sapui5

I'm writing here after a couple of hours of reading everything available on-line, including SAPUI5 Explored Apps, API, etcs.

I need to use Image with Maps to define and capture different clickable areas in an image.

SAPUI5 explored says there is an UseMap parameter, but don't provide enough info or example. I've tried and can't map and get the clicked location.

The API offers sap.m.ImageHelper, with one parameter to use maps. But it also lacks example or enough documentation.

Finally, I'm aware that there's some examples on-line using sap.ui.commons. But I couldn't find any example using sap.m

Anyone has a real working example of this?

Thank you!

Regards,

Douglas

Comment: The imagemap itself is the standard element `<map>`, which has a name attribute. This name goes in the `useMap` parameter. Other than that it looks to be completely standard html. Havent' used it, check an imagemap tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

The sap.m.Image useMap property simply adds a useMap property to the  element. However you need to define a map element  with the same name as in the useMap property along with the regions.

You could use the HTML control from the sap.ui.core library to add a HTML map element to the page.

```
<Image src="img/someImage.jpg"
    width="200px"
    useMap="regions"
>
</Image>

<core:HTML content='&lt;map name=&quot;regions&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;area shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;0,0,82,126&quot; href=&quot;link1.html&quot; alt=&quot;Link 1&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;area shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;90,90, 158,103&quot; href=&quot;link2.htm&quot; alt=&quot;Link 2&quot;&gt;
                    &lt;/map&gt;'>
</core:HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to revert to a stringified version of your map coding.
 Here's how you can provide a map as the `useMap` parameter for a `sap.m.image` by referencing the `html` namespace (Note the declaration `xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` at the top):

```
<mvc:View controllerName="xy.controller.Master" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" >
  <App>
    <pages>
      <Page title="{i18n>title}">
        <content>
          <Image src="img/Blume.PNG" densityAware="false" width="" useMap="Map">
            <layoutData>
              <FlexItemData growFactor="1"/>
            </layoutData>
          </Image>

          <html:map name="Map" id="Map">
            <html:area alt="" title="" href="www.google.de" shape="poly" coords="384,505,444,507,444,528,390,527"/>
            <html:area alt="" title="" href="www.google.de" shape="poly" coords="426,582,494,583,494,636,426,632"/>
          </html:map>

        </content>
      </Page>
    </pages>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

Credits: https://answers.sap.com/questions/290270/how-use-sapmimage-with-usemap-and-get-the-clicked.html